# Parse a part of the result of a bash command to store it into a variable

Tags: bash

My question is really a `bash` question even if it talks about mounting a disk.

During the creation of a VM, by a script, I mount this disk:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb /data
```

And I would like to keep it every time my system start. Make this mount become automatic. I learnt that I had to edit the `/etc/fstab` file for that : append a line on it.

When my disk is mounted, I have to run a command:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: UUID="238d1293-918e-42e1-a081-a41f497636d0" TYPE="ext4"
```

To get the UUID I need to mention in the line I append on my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID=238d1293-918e-42e1-a081-a41f497636d0       /data      ext4    defaults      0       0
```

**My question is:** May I parse by `bash` the result of the `blkid` command, catch the part `UUID="238d1293-918e-42e1-a081-a41f497636d0"` from the `/dev/sdb: UUID="238d1293-918e-42e1-a081-a41f497636d0" TYPE="ext4"` content and store it into a variable?

Comment: BTW, you realize you can ask `findmnt` to just tell you the UUID directly, so you don't need to parse `blkid` at all?

Comment: Good idea ! I didn't know this command. However, a `sudo findmnt /dev/sdb -o UUID` respond with two lines : one containing "UUID" the second "238d1293-918e-42e1-a081-a41f497636d0". So I still have to parse.

Comment: The `-n` flag suppresses that header. And if it didn't, you could ignore it yourself by `read`ing it into a variable you then ignore: `{ read header; read -r uuid; } < <(findmnt /dev/sdb -o UUID)`

Comment: Thanks a lot to all ! You gave me plenty of solutions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter substitution:

```
uuid=$(sudo blkid /dev/sdb)
uuid=${uuid#*UUID=\"}  # Remove from left up to UUID="
uuid=${uuid%%\"*}      # Remove from right from the leftmost "
echo "$uuid"
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash's built-in regex support is suited to task. In the below function, we're testing the output of `blkid` against the regex `UUID="([^"]+)"`, and emitting the match group contents (everything inside the parenthesis) if a match is found:

```
uuid_for_device() {
  local uuid_re blkid_text      # Declare our locals so we don't leak into global scope
  uuid_re='UUID="([^"]+)"'      # Save the regex to a variable; less gotchas this way
  blkid_text=$(sudo blkid "$1") || return # Collect the data we're going to match against
  [[ $blkid_text =~ $uuid_re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" # Emit output if regex matches
}
```

...will emit your desired UUID given `uuid_for_device /dev/sda`, which you can capture into a variable as usual (`sda_uuid=$(uuid_for_device /dev/sda)`).

---

That said, for your real-world use case, you're better off just using a more appropriate tool for the job:

```
uuid_for_device() { findmnt -n -o UUID "$1"; }

sda_uuid=$(uuid_for_device /dev/sda)
```

Or, of course, simply:

```
sda_uuid=$(findmnt -n -o UUID /dev/sda)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sed:

```
YOUR_COMMAND | sed -e 's/.*UUID="\([0-9a-f-]*\)".*/\1/'
```

You can use backticks for example to store it:

```
a=`YOUR_COMMAND | sed -e 's/.*UUID="\([0-9a-f-]*\)".*/\1/'`

echo $a
```

Comment: Also, there's a caveat with this one in that if the output *doesn't have any `UUID` string at all*, the `sed` expression given in the first revision of this answer will pass the content through unmodified.

Comment: Also, `echo $a` should be `echo "$a"`; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: (...and re: backticks, see [BashFAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)

Comment: By using your solution, DumbNewbie, and the one suggested by Coroba, I wrote : `uuid=$(sudo blkid /dev/sdb | sed -e 's/.*UUID="\([0-9a-f-]*\)".*/\1/')`. It works and it pleases me. Thanks !

Comment: @Marc glad to help.